# IBM Cloud access policies: How to check for specific policy using CLI?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, command-line-interface

IBM Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) allows to define access policies to allow a service to access another service in a specific role. I can create such policies using the IBM Cloud CLI. However, how can I find a specific policy using the CLI? I can list them with the following command, but not filter.

```
> ibmcloud iam authorization-policies 
OK

ID:                        11111111-xxxx-43d4-927f-9c4fda1d0e0a   
Source service name:       cloud-object-storage   
Source service instance:   All instances   
Target service name:       kms   
Target service instance:   All instances   
Roles:                     Reader   

ID:                        11111111-xxxx-4734-aa28-2a9e56ae4391   
Source service name:       cloud-object-storage   
Source service instance:   All instances   
Target service name:       kms   
Target service instance:   6db42dc7-8edd-490c-bda6-7ad4c44d7c71   
Roles:                     Reader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something can be done using `grep` and the **after context** option. The following filters for the beginning of a policy entry and keeps the next few lines thereafter. Further invocations of `grep` search for other policy properties. This could be done for all instances or for specific instance IDs.

```
ibmcloud iam authorization-policies | \
   grep -A 4 "Source service name:       cloud-object-storage" | \
   grep -A 3 "All instances" | \
   grep -A 2 "kms" | \
   grep "Reader"
```

Idea is taken from this [toolchain script](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/scripts/pipeline-DEPLOY.sh) as part of this [IBM Cloud tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-e2e-security.html).